# Have 2 array with 5 number between 0-8,go through array if any possible combo match the numbers in array. if yes say winner. Combos = given in my ans

Tags: javascript, loops, constructor, tic-tac-toe

Ans :

```
var p1arr = [];
var p2arr = [];


const GameBoard = (() => {
    const PlayerFactory = (name, mark, turn) => {
        return { name, mark, turn }
    };

    const player1 = PlayerFactory("Player 1", "X", true);
    const player2 = PlayerFactory("Player 2", "O", false);



    let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
    boxes.forEach(boxes => {
        boxes.addEventListener('click', e => {
            if (player1.turn === true) {
                boxes.textContent = player1.mark;
                // alert("Kaam 1 ho gya");
                p1arr[e.target.id] = player1.mark;
                console.log(p1arr);
                player1.turn = false;
                player2.turn = true;
                checkwinner();
            }
            else if (player2.turn === true) {
                boxes.textContent = player2.mark;
                // alert("Kaam 2 ho gya");
                p2arr[e.target.id] = player2.mark;
                console.log(p2arr);
                player1.turn = true;
                player2.turn = false;
                checkwinner();
            }
        });
    })

})();

const winCombos = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8]
];

function checkwinner(){
   
  // Check if any winCombos match the numbers in array1
  var isWinner1 = checkWinCombos(p1arr);
  if (isWinner1) {
    console.log("Winner found in array1!");
  }
  
  // Check if any winCombos match the numbers in array2
  var isWinner2 = checkWinCombos(p2arr);
  if (isWinner2) {
    console.log("Winner found in array2!");
  }

  // Function to check if any winCombos match the given array
  function checkWinCombos(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < winCombos.length; i++) {
      var combo = winCombos[i];
      var isMatch = true;
      for (var j = 0; j < combo.length; j++) {
        if (array.indexOf(combo[j]) === -1) {
          isMatch = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (isMatch) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

I have tried all the combinations but I didn't get the result written "Winner". Please help me to solve the problem as I am making a tic tac toe game using java script.I have started the code and I had taken the input from user but not found the winner. I know I have to work a lot on this project but I got stuck in between and can't able to find where to go.

Comment: Please explain which input you provide, and what you expect to get from it. Currently we have no idea how you defined `p1arr` or `p2arr`. When I set `p1arr = [3, 6, 0]` I get the Winner message. What did you provide?

Comment: I'm guessing `p1arr` and `p2arr` are the "2 array with 5 number between 0-8" from the title, but we should not have to guess, it should be made clear and unambiguous.

Comment: Does `-1` mean, "there is no entry in this square"?  If so, then presumably you correctly initialized the array to all `-1`s as needed.  But the logic is a little weird.  If any of the potential lines contains a `-1` square then it's no match.  But just because all the cells are not `-1` doesn't mean that they are all equal.  I'm not sure what you are using to denote an `X` or an `O`, but presumably you should be checking to see if `array[combo[j]] === array[combo[0]]` to see that they all "match".

Comment: @Wyck, the -1 is the result from `indexOf`, it's not the value in the grid.

Comment: @Wyck I think op is storing numbers from 0 to 8 in the arrays

Comment: Oh I see.  `p1arr` is intended to be a list of the indices of all the squares in which a player 1 token (e.g. an `X`) has been placed and `p2arr` is a list of the indices of all the squares in which a player 2 token (e.g. an `O`) has been placed.  Is that right?

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. What's the problem to solve?

Comment: I'm confused a third time now.  `p1arr[e.target.id] = player1.mark;` suggests that, assuming `e.target.id` is a number from 0-8 (i.e. the square index) then `p1arr` works more like a snapshot of the gameboard. for example, if `X` goes in the center square (index 4) then the `p1arr` array will look like `[ <4 empty items>, 'X' ]`.  This array does not contain a 4, as would be found to be absent by `array.indexOf(combo[j]) === -1` but rather you should be checking:  if `array[combo[j]] === undefined` that means a token belonging to that player has not been placed in that square.

Comment: Please give me a correct code to get a winner when input array is matched with wincombos array.

Comment: @Wyck I think my mistake is that I have apparently use the wrong way to put my "X" and "O" in an array of p1arr and p2arr respectively. But still I don't know how to out them in a correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were basically there.  You can change:

```
if (array.indexOf(combo[j]) === -1) {
```

to:

```
if (!array[combo[j]]) {
```

The reason is that you are storing an `X` or an `O` in the array, not a number. For example, after playing `X` in the center square you perform `p1arr[e.target.id] = player1.mark;`.  I presume the `id` of that square is `4` and therefore, you will assign `p1arr[4] = 'X'`, leaving your `p1arr` looking like this:

```json
[
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  "X"
]
```

To correctly check to see if a square has a mark in it, you don't have to change much, you can just check the truthiness of the value in the array.  `array[combo[j]]` will be `X` or `O` (truthy) where there is a mark, and `undefined` (falsy) where there is no mark.

Your non-working original code was checking to see if the array contained the index of the cell.  For example, when playing X in the center square, it was looking to see if `p1arr` contained an element equal to `4`, which it clearly does not.  But rather, there will be some `X`'s at various indices depending on the state of the game board.

#### Full example (with working HTML and CSS)

```js
var p1arr = [];
var p2arr = [];


const GameBoard = (() => {
    const PlayerFactory = (name, mark, turn) => {
        return { name, mark, turn }
    };

    const player1 = PlayerFactory("Player 1", "X", true);
    const player2 = PlayerFactory("Player 2", "O", false);



    let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
    boxes.forEach(boxes => {
        boxes.addEventListener('click', e => {
            if (player1.turn === true) {
                boxes.textContent = player1.mark;
                // alert("Kaam 1 ho gya");
                p1arr[e.target.id] = player1.mark;
                console.log(p1arr);
                player1.turn = false;
                player2.turn = true;
                checkwinner();
            }
            else if (player2.turn === true) {
                boxes.textContent = player2.mark;
                // alert("Kaam 2 ho gya");
                p2arr[e.target.id] = player2.mark;
                console.log(p2arr);
                player1.turn = true;
                player2.turn = false;
                checkwinner();
            }
        });
    })

})();

const winCombos = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8]
];

function checkwinner(){
   
  // Check if any winCombos match the numbers in array1
  var isWinner1 = checkWinCombos(p1arr);
  if (isWinner1) {
    console.log("Winner found in array1!");
  }
  
  // Check if any winCombos match the numbers in array2
  var isWinner2 = checkWinCombos(p2arr);
  if (isWinner2) {
    console.log("Winner found in array2!");
  }

  // Function to check if any winCombos match the given array
  function checkWinCombos(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < winCombos.length; i++) {
      var combo = winCombos[i];
      var isMatch = true;
      for (var j = 0; j < combo.length; j++) {
        if (!array[combo[j]]) {
          isMatch = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (isMatch) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  margin: 5px auto;
}
.vert {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
.hori {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="0" class="box"></td>
    <td id="1" class="box vert"></td>
    <td id="2" class="box"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="3" class="box hori"></td>
    <td id="4" class="box vert hori"></td>
    <td id="5" class="box hori"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="6" class="box"></td>
    <td id="7" class="box vert"></td>
    <td id="8" class="box"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```